# Send messages using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

am trying to establish a communication link using python sockets and send messages that is received by the other side(server) , in which i always encounter the same problem 
here is the code

Client Code :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket() 
host = raw_input("Enter a Hostname : ")
port = input ("Enter a port to communicate on : ")
message = raw_input("What do you want to send (Up , Down , Left , Right) : ")

s.connect((host,port))
while True :
if message == "Up" or "up" :
    M = 'U'
elif message == "Down" or "down" :
    M = 'D'
elif message == "Left" or "left" :
    M = 'L'
elif message == "Right" or "right" :
    M = 'R'
else :
    print ("Please Enter a Valued Word : ")
    M = '0'
    s.send(M)
    print ("This is the sent messages %s to IP %s", (M , host))
print (s.recev(1024))
s.close
```

Server Code :

```
import socket 

s = socket.socket()       
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 8080              
s.bind((host, port)) 

s.listen(5)                
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Connected')
   c.close()
```

**i always get the following error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "third_att.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((host,port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
ailed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to INADDR_ANY "0.0.0.0":

```
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
```

or enter the hostname instead of localhost.

Try printing hostname on server before 'bind()'.

Also, do not forget to enable SO_REUSEADDR just before bind:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Comment: I've changed the protocol of sending from TCP to UDP and its going well , Thanks for your help.